# JSON data getting retrieved from mongodb with formats added explicitly inside field e.g.({"field": {$numberInt: "20"}}). How to process that data?

Tags: mongodb, axios, formatting, realm

I have used mongo import to import data into mongodb from csv files. I am trying to retrieve data from an Mongodb realm service. The returned data for the entry is as follows:

```
{
       "_id": "6124edd04543fb222e",
       "Field1": "some string",
       "Field2": {
         "$numberDouble": "145.81"
       },
       "Field3": {
         "$numberInt": "0"
       },
       "Field4": {
         "$numberInt": "15"
       },
       "Field5": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
     
     }
```

How do I convert this into normal JSON by removing $numberInt and $numberDouble like :

```
{
       "_id": "6124edd04543fb222e",
       "Field1": "some string",
       "Field2": 145.8,
       "Field3": 0,

       "Field4": 15,

       "Field5":  0
     
     }
```

The fields are also different for different documents so cannot use Mongoose directly. Are there any solutions to this?
Also would help to know why the numbers are being stored as $numberInt:"".

### **Edit:**

For anyone with the same problem this is how I solved it.

The array of documents is in EJSON format instead of JSON like said in the upvoted answer. To covert it back into normal JSON, I used JSON.stringify to first convert each document I got from map function into string and then parsed it using EJSON.parse with

**{strict:false} (*this option is important*)**

option to convert it into normal JSON.

```
{restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
          restaurant=EJSON.parse(JSON.stringify(restaurant),{strict:false});
}
```

EJSON.parse [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/package/mongodb-extjson) here. The module to be installed and imported is mongodb-extjson.

Comment: try export csv instead of json

Comment: @mohammadNaimi I was getting the data using db.collection.find() and not exporting it but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format with `$numberInt` etc. is called (MongoDB) Extended JSON.

You are getting it on the output side either because this is how you inserted your data (meaning your inserted data was incorrect, you need to fix the ingestion side) or because you requested extended JSON serialization.

If the data in the database is correct, and you want non-extended JSON output, you generally need to write your own serializers to JSON since there are multiple possibilities of how to format the data. MongoDB's JSON output format is the Extended JSON you're seeing in your first quote.